# fade in or opacity in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

`enter code here`i have an image, which i an sliding from bottom to middle in my splash screen.
in addition to slideTransaction, i want the image to fade in with the slide, so that opacity changes from 0 to 1 while it slides upwards.
is it done by using animation twice on the widget, or is there any other way?

i have added the code only about the widget, that i am sliding up, and now want to animate fade-in.

this is initialization:

```
 AnimationController animationController;
  Animation<Offset> animation1;
```

this is in init state:

```
 animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
    );

 animation1 = Tween<Offset>(
       begin: Offset.zero, end: Offset(0, -3 ))
        .animate(animationController);
    animationController.forward();
```

and the following is the widget:

```
 Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
     child: SlideTransition(
        position: animation1,
        child: Transform.scale(
        scale: 1.5,
        child:Image.asset('assets/images/Capture.PNG'),
        ),),),
```

Answer (score 0):

The `MultiTween` widget in the [simple_animations](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_animations) package might be what you're looking for. Here is a widget that I reused in multiple projects :

```
class FadeIn extends StatelessWidget {
  final double delay;
  final Widget child;
  FadeIn(this.delay, this.child);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tween = MultiTween<String>()
      ..add("opacity", Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0), Duration(milliseconds: 500))
      ..add("translateY", Tween(begin: 130.0, end: 0.0), Duration(milliseconds: 500), Curves.easeOut);

    return PlayAnimation<MultiTweenValues<String>>(
      delay: Duration(milliseconds: (300 * delay).round()),
      duration: tween.duration,
      curve: Curves.decelerate, // or fastOutSlowIn
      tween: tween,
      child: child,
      builder: (context, child, value) => Opacity(
            opacity: value.get("opacity"),
            child: Transform.translate(
                offset: Offset(0, value.get("translateY")), child: child),
          ),
    );
  }
}
```